# IE8 position bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, position

All browsers works fine, except IE8. I have a slide, you can check out here: [Left/Right arrow problem with position.](http://chamacomunicacao.com.br/realnet)

The code is this one:

```
#prev {
    background: url(img/set-esq.png);
    width: 62px;
    height: 117px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#next {
    background: url(img/set-dir.png);
    width: 62px;
    height: 117px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 150px;
}
```

Works fine with all browsers, except with IE8. The arrow "glues" with the slide margin. I don't know how can I solve this problem anymore.

Can you guys give me a hint or a solution?

Comment: I tested in ie8 and works fine.

Comment: It's very close to the margin. Sorry to post at the jsFiddle, but since I cannot post "spaces" here, I had to :/ http://jsfiddle.net/BsPfg/

Comment: Oh! I saw < > is sitting in upper in ie is that your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, It's working in all browsers except in IE8. But note to your `.slide` selector to give `position: relative;` and then only position your arrow with absolute position, this time you need to change the top, right, bottom or left value of absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: I was thinking about conditional tags for IE8. Because is working with Chrome etcetera but not working with IE (always).

Comment: Yeah, It solved. I created a new #id named slide-relative. Works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

give it a try
put the a tags in the div with class=caroufredsel_wrapper
i put it before the ul
and then use this style

```
#prev {
background: url(img/set-esq.png);
width: 62px;
height: 117px;
position: absolute;
top: 191px;
z-index: 2;
}
#next {
background: url(img/set-dir.png);
width: 62px;
height: 117px;
position: absolute;
top: 191px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 2;
}
```